# Bluetooth Trackpad losing settings on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, bluetooth

I have an Apple Trackpad 1 connected to a Kubuntu 16.04 system (Intel NUC).

The trackpad basically works, but it loses its configuration settings. I have configured it to use reverse vertical scrolling, but it does not hold that setting for long. After a few minutes it reverts to 'normal' scrolling and shows a message in the settings pane to indicate that it is not using my settings. It's really irritating because I'm never quite sure which way I'm going to scroll!

[image]

Any suggestions please?